# IIFE returns map function, map can't use var

Tags: javascript, closures, pouchdb, iife

I have a function I want to use in a map operation, which compares a local variable with the doc returned from the map. I tried it directly, and I tried it as an IIFE, and both ways it's complaining that map can't find a variable named `boatNumber`:

```
   var mymap = (function() {
        var boatNumber = $('#add_result_boat_number').val();
        return function(doc) {
            if (doc.boatnumber == boatNumber) {
                emit(doc._id, {boatClass: doc.boatClass, p1name: doc.p1name, p2name: doc.p2name});
            }
        }
    })();

    ro.pdb.query(mymap).then(function(response) {
        var results = response.rows;
        // do stuff later
    }).catch(function(error) {
        ro.reporter(error);
    });
```

If I replace `boatNumber` with a constant in the `==` it works fine. So how do I get the `boatNumber` to be recognized in the map function?

**Update**

```
Error messages are:
The user's map/reduce function threw an uncaught error.
You can debug this error by doing:
myDatabase.on('error', function (err) { debugger; });
Please double-check your map/reduce function.
```

followed by

```
ReferenceError: "boatNumber is not defined"
    anonymous file:///Users/ptomblin/Dropbox/KayakResults/js/pouchdb-7.1.1.min.js line 7 > Function:5
    Zn file:///Users/ptomblin/Dropbox/KayakResults/js/pouchdb-7.1.1.min.js:7
    n file:///Users/ptomblin/Dropbox/KayakResults/js/pouchdb-7.1.1.min.js:7
    e file:///Users/ptomblin/Dropbox/KayakResults/js/pouchdb-7.1.1.min.js:7
```

Comment: what exactly is the error message? `boatNumber` is certainly in scope everywhere it is used in the code you've shown.

Comment: @RobinZigmond updated in question.

Comment: I do have the feeling that `mymap` gets stringified, sent somewhere else, and evaluated there. I guess it has to be pure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function passed to `query` gets stringified and sent to the database. Then it gets evaluated there. Thus you cannot access anything from the outside, it has to be pure, so in other words you can only access the `doc` passed and the [builtin methods](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/query-server/javascript.html) (yes, the docs should really mention that).

As it seems, what you want to do can be done trivially with a regular `find()`query:

```
    var boatNumber = $('#add_result_boat_number').val();
    ro.pdb.find({
     selector: {
       boatnumber: boatNumber,
     },
     fields: ["boatClass", "p1name", "p2name"]
    }).then(...)
```

Comment: The documentation states that I'd need to install another plugin for that. I was hoping to avoid complicating this more than I had to. (By the way, well done for spotting this was a PouchDB problem even though I forgot to tag it as such).

Comment: Well, I just used MongoDB so far (the queries are heavily inspired by that), but IMO it's really strange that you have to load another library for queries. I mean thats what DBs are all about ... But nevertheless running some JS over a lot of entries seems a very bad idea performance wise, so I'd really try to work with a real db query somehow

Comment: It has to be pure *and not close over anything*.

Comment: @bergi with "pure" I meant "access nothing else except the parameters and the builtins provided by the environment" (I had to dig through quite a lot of documentation just to find *nothing*.

Comment: Oh, and the instructions for installing pouchdb-find are wrong: `npm install pouchdb-find` returns ENOTFOUND.

Comment: I'm running this totally locally, not talking to CouchDB or any back end yet.